# Check diff against file on the server

Tags: svn, diff

I have a working copy of a repository on my machine, and I know that it has been updated on the server. I would like to know how to get the difference between the new version and the version in my working copy by using `svn` command line arguments.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/150213/subversion-how-to-compare-differences-between-incoming-changes

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The working copy is revision BASE. The latest copy from the repository is revision HEAD. This will compare your working copy against the HEAD revision:

```
svn diff -r HEAD <file>
```

Actually that'll spit the changes out in reverse, i.e. it tells you how to go from HEAD to BASE. So technically you want:

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD <file>
```

Can you spare the keyboard strokes? Only you and your deity know that answer.

Comment: The working copy file can be different from base (when you have local modifications to the file). You should realize that it diffs the file without the local modifications with the server.

Comment: Later answer addresses original question of diffing local modifications to HEAD

Comment: BASE is _not_ the working copy, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html

Answer (score 18):

The difference between *working copy* and `HEAD`; the changes which would need to be made to what is now in the repository (`HEAD`), to produce your *working copy*:

```
svn diff -r HEAD --old=<file>
```

Of possible interest, the difference between `BASE` and `HEAD`; changes that have been checked into the repository since you last updated *working copy*:

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD <file>
```

And of course the difference between `BASE` and *working copy*; the changes you have made since you last updated *working copy*:

```
svn diff <file>
```

There are three versions being discussed: `BASE`, *working copy*, and `HEAD`.

- `BASE`: `<file>` as last checked out / updated. What *working copy* would revert to after using `svn revert`
- *working copy*: local modifications to `<file>` which has been checked out / updated as recently as `BASE`
- `HEAD`: latest modifications in repository. Equivalent to `BASE` *iff* no changes have been committed since `<file>` was checked out / updated as *working copy*.