# How to diff an svn working copy with its original version?

Tags: svn, diff

How to diff an svn working copy with its original version, when the original version is not necessarily in the HEAD revision. For example, if I checked-out from version 2080 and someone else has already checked-in as 2081 I  see the diffs with 2081 and not with 2080 like I do on TortoiseSVN, when I use svn shell commands suggested in:

[Check diff against file on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773345/check-diff-against-file-on-the-server)
(using diff)

and:

[SVN: how to compare working copy with repository revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926896/svn-how-to-compare-working-copy-with-repository-revision)
(using show-updates)

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "original" if it isn't the repository version your working copy points to but the [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) subcommand has a `--revision (-r)` switch.

Comment: Please, tell us what you mean by 'original version' and 'is not necessarily in HEAD'. Have you checked the examples provided in `svn diff` reference http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html ?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear. I'm looking for a one-liner to do this (which I haven't found in the reference @bahrep  suggeseted) and I'm also interested in knowing whether it can't be done with svn and need scripting.